# Response values overlapping in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making an application where I need to have multiple Ajax requests. But the problem is that I am getting same response values for both Ajax requests.
In each request there needs to be a data named `activityCode` but doing that I keep getting the value of `ScoreBoardResponse` even in the `heartbeat function` too. If I rename anyone of the `activityCode` to any other name the problem gets sorted. But why does this happen?

Here is the following code:

**JS**

```
var allJoined = false;
    var roomName = $('#room').val();
    var playerNameSet = function () {
        if(!allJoined) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "gameEngine/app.php",
                data: {
                    activityCode: 1,
                    room: roomName
                },
                success: function (ScoreBoardResponse) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(ScoreBoardResponse);
                    var count = Object.keys(obj).length;
                    if (count == 1) {
                        playerOne_name.html(obj.p1_name);
                        setTimeout(playerNameSet, 3000);
                    }
                    else if (count == 2) {
                        playerOne_name.html(obj.p1_name);
                        playerTwo_name.html(obj.p2_name);
                        allJoined = true;
                        //Start the heartbeat to check if the other player is alive
                        setTimeout(startHeartbeat, 15000);
                        clearTimeout(playerNameSet);
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    setTimeout(playerNameSet, 3000);

function startHeartbeat() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gameEngine/app.php",
            data: {
                activityCode: 2,
                room: roomName
            },
            success: function(beat) {
                console.log(beat);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(startHeartbeat, 15000);
    }
```

**PHP**

```
.
.
.
elseif (isset($_POST['activityCode']) == 1 && isset($_POST['room'])) {
    $response = $gameHandler->getPlayerOrder($_POST['room']);

    echo $response;
}
elseif (isset($_POST['activityCode']) == 2 && isset($_POST['room'])) {
    echo "request reached here";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php) returns either `true` or `false` if the POST variable exists or not. It does not return the variable value, the you need to add another check in your condition :

```
elseif (isset($_POST['activityCode']) && $_POST['activityCode'] == 1 && isset($_POST['room'])) {
    $response = $gameHandler->getPlayerOrder($_POST['room']);

    echo $response;
}
elseif (isset($_POST['activityCode']) && $_POST['activityCode'] == 2 && isset($_POST['room'])) {
    echo "request reached here";
}
```